Any ways to avoid using many if statements
I just finished learning python basics from CS50 and I am now trying to make a small game program for practice. Halfway through I ran into a potential problem.
To sum the game up, it is like this:

User inputs 5 numbers from 0 to 9
The game is programmed with multiple fixed patterns for the 5 numbers
The program determines whether the user's input matches any of the patterns or not
Based on what it matches (if it does) the program gives the user a score

Example:
User's input - 1,2,3,4,5
Possible patterns - a,a+1,a+2,a+3,a+4  1 point
                  - a,a+2,a+4,a+6,a+8  2 points
                  - a,a+1,a+3,a+5,a+7  3 points

So in this case the user gets 1 point.
My current problem is, I am trying to make a lot of different patterns (Like 20), but the only way I know as of now is to use an if statement for each pattern like this:
if .....

if .....

if .....

Doing this for each pattern feels wrong. I tried searching for ways to reduce the number of if statements but methods like using jump table (dictionaries) do not seem to work here. Thanks in advance.

In your example, what is a?

a is the smallest number out of the 5 numbers the user inputs

You could put your patterns and scores in lists. For example store the patterns as lambda expressions, that can be evaluated based on the input a.
Then you can iterate over the patterns, evaluate them and compare the result with the user input.
user_input = [12, 14, 16, 18, 20]
a = user_input[0]

# define your patterns and their scores
patterns = [
    lambda x: [x, x + 1, x + 2, x + 3, x + 4],
    lambda x: [x, x + 2, x + 4, x + 6, x + 8],
    lambda x: [x, x + 3, x + 6, x + 9, x + 12],
]
scores = [1, 2, 3]


def compare_list(list1, list2):
    return list1 == list2


score = 0
for idx, pattern in enumerate(patterns):
    if compare_list(user_input, pattern(a)):
        print("Pattern found")
        score = scores[idx]
        break

print(f"Score: {score}")

You might need to sort the lists before checking equality, depending on the patterns you want to match.

The match/case functionality was added in python 3.10 so if you're version limited and therefore limited to if statements, maybe have the checker call another function so you can return if an if statement is matched (so you limit the number of if statements).  Then add math to your if statements so they cover multiple scenarios.
Example:
<-SNIP->
def check_value(a, value):
    checkvalue = value - a
    # sort the if statements from highest to lowest return
    if checkvalue%2 == 1:
        return 3
    if checkvalue%2 == 0:
        return 2
    if checkvalue <= 4:
        return 1
    # etc
    return 0

# Call the checker in your other method:
# a is target value
# value is under input value
win_result = check_value(a, value)

<-SNIP->
Edit: I see now that there may be multiple win results for each difference, which would make if or match with return not a useful solution. In this case you could use a dict to store your difference/win pairs. Note: You can use integer keys for a dict if you define the dict with {}, but not with dict().
Example:
<-SNIP->
result_dict = {
    1 : 4, # 1+3
    2 : 3, # 1+2
    3 : 4, # 1+3
    4 : 3, # 1+3
    5 : 3, # 3
    # and so on
    }

win_result = result_dict[user_value-target_value]

<-SNIP->

You can use a list or dict to store the tuple (distance_between_element, points)
Calculate the distance between the list items.
input = [1,2,3,4,5]
result = []
for i in range(input)-1:
   result.append(list[i+1] -list[i])

Now you need a dict.
with theKey [1,1,1,1]  and Value 1 it would a, a+1, a+2, a+3, a+4 and get 1 point.

If users enters 1 2 3 4 5 then this will be string so conversion to a List of ints would be required for this answer. Also it is best not to shadow the name input which is used for a specific purpose in Python.

def pattern1(numbers):
    # Check if numbers match the pattern a, a+1, a+2, a+3, a+4
    return all(numbers[i] == numbers[0] + i for i in range(len(numbers)))

def pattern2(numbers):
    # Check if numbers match the pattern a, a+2, a+4, a+6, a+8
    return all(numbers[i] == numbers[0] + 2*i for i in range(len(numbers)))

def pattern3(numbers):
    # Check if numbers match the pattern a, a+1, a+3, a+5, a+7
    return all(numbers[i] == numbers[0] + sum(range(i+1)) for i in range(len(numbers)))

# Dictionary to store patterns and their scores
patterns = {
    pattern1: 1,
    pattern2: 2,
    pattern3: 3
}

def evaluate_input(user_input):
    # Convert the user input string to a list of integers
    numbers = list(map(int, user_input.split(',')))

    # Initialize score
    score = 0

    # Check each pattern
    for pattern, points in patterns.items():
        if pattern(numbers):
            score += points

    return score

# Main program
user_input = input("Enter 5 numbers separated by commas (e.g., 1,2,3,4,5): ")
score = evaluate_input(user_input)
print(f"Your score: {score}")

Explanation:

Pattern Functions: pattern1, pattern2, and pattern3 are functions that check for specific patterns in the input numbers. These can be adjusted or expanded based on the game's rules.
Patterns Dictionary: Each pattern function is associated with a point value in a dictionary. This allows for easy expansion or modification of the scoring system.
Evaluate Input: The evaluate_input function converts the user input into a list of integers, then checks each pattern by calling the corresponding pattern function. If a pattern matches, it adds the associated points to the score.
Main Program: Prompts the user for input, evaluates it, and prints the score.

This approach makes your code more organized and scalable, simplifying the addition of new patterns or changes to scoring. It reduces complexity and increases maintainability by encapsulating pattern logic within individual functions.

Assuming that your Python version allows match-case (and that each entry follows your examples of successive increment/decrement of the first number) then you could convert the input into a pattern and match these to produce the score using the code below. If the entry arrangements can follow a more complex variation then the conversion would need to be suitably modified.
user_str = input('enter five numbers ')

def func(entry): 
    comp = []
    vals = entry.split()
    for num in vals:
       comp.append(int(num) - int(vals[0]))
    match comp[1:]:         # compare all but first element
        case [1, 2, 3, 4]: points = 1
        case [2, 4, 6, 8]: points = 2
        case [1, 3, 4, 7]: points = 3
        case _: points = 0   # catch all non-matching patterns
    return points

print(func(user_str))

so if the user enters 1 2 3 4 5 then the code produces 1

Nice catch on seeing the user inputs all the numbers at once! I think some combination of your answer and mine would be ideal. So the method would return for each match instead of setting the return value and returning at the end of the method.

This will be simpler and easy to understand. The idea here is to find out hcf. hcf is nothing but the biggest number by which all the elements of the input can be divided. After finding hcf, if all the elements of the input is divided by hcf, you'll get the pattern directly.
# Get comma separated input
usr_entry = input()

# convert input into list
usr_entry = usr_entry.split(',')

#convert each element into int 
usr_entry = [int(float(x)) for x in usr_entry]

# create a dict keys being pattern with a = 1
dct = {(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) : 1,
        (1, 3, 5, 7, 9) : 2,
        (1, 2, 4, 6, 8) : 3}

# find the smallest number of the user input
small = min(usr_entry)

if tuple(usr_entry) not in dct.keys():
    # Iterate from small to 1 in reverse step being -1
    for i in range(small, 0, -1):

        if i != 1:
            #find out hcf and break
            if all(x % i == 0 for x in usr_entry):
                hcf = i; break
                
                
else: hcf = 1

# Divide all the user input by hcf
usr_entry = [x/hcf for x in usr_entry]

# convert the usr_entry to tuple
usr_entry = tuple(usr_entry)

print(dct[usr_entry])


You can use "Switch (match)" or "Map (object shape data)" in most languages for such scenario.
example:
def http_error(status):
    match status:
        case 400:
            return "Bad request"
        case 404:
            return "Not found"
        case _:
            return "Something's wrong with the internet"


How would this be used for the question being asked?

@user19077881 If you don't understand it, don't use it
